# replace historical data of a data.frame with the most recent year data in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, tidyverse, lubridate

I want to replace `Jan 01 to Jun 25` of all the years in `FakeData` with data from `Ob2020` for the `two variables (Level & Flow)` of my `data.frame`. Here is what i have started and am looking for suggestions to achieving my goal.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(1500)

FakeData <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), to = as.Date("2018-12-31"), by = "days"),
                       Level = runif(3287, 0, 30), Flow = runif(3287, 1,10))

Ob2020 <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), to = as.Date("2020-06-25"), by = "days"),
                     Level = runif(177, 0, 30), Flow = runif(177, 1,10))
```

Comment: In your example, some of the Jan01 to Jun25 doesnt  have corresponding values in 0b2020.  if that is the case, I guess it should remain as such right?

Comment: Yes- this is because the year 2020 has an extra day in Feb (leap year).

Comment: I added a solution with `data.table` join perhaps it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way using `dplyr` and `lubridate` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

FakeData %>%
  mutate(day = day(Date), month = month(Date)) %>%
  left_join(Ob2020 %>%
              mutate(day = day(Date), month = month(Date)), 
              by = c('day', 'month')) %>%
   mutate(Level = coalesce(Level.y, Level.x), 
          Flow = coalesce(Flow.y, Flow.x)) %>%
  select(Date = Date.x, Level, Flow)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you dont mind a `data.table` solution, here is an update join:

```
library(data.table)
#extract year and month of the date
setDT(FakeData)[, c("day", "mth") := .(mday(Date), month(Date))]
setDT(Ob2020)[, c("day", "mth") := .(mday(Date), month(Date))]

#print to console to show old values        
head(FakeData)
head(Ob2020)

cols <- c("Level", "Flow")
FakeData[Ob2020[mth<=6L & day<=25], on=.(day, mth),
    (cols) := mget(paste0("i.", cols))]

#print to console to show new values
head(FakeData)
```